# django view integrityError

Tags: django, django-views

I need help with the following code. I think I'm almost there. I'm trying to create a view with works for both editing and adding a new object. However, on saving I get the error listed below.

I wonder if someone can show me where I'm going wrong?

Thank you.

**view.py**

```
def group(request, id=None):

    if id:
        group = get_object_or_404(Groups, pk=id)

    else:
        group = Groups()

        # If we had a POST then get the request post values.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = GroupFrom(request.POST)
        # Check we have valid data
        if form.is_valid():
            group = Groups(
                name=form.cleaned_data['name'],
                description=form.cleaned_data['description'],
                active=form.cleaned_data['active'],
                user=request.user
            )

            group.save()

    else:
        form = GroupFrom(instance=group)

    context = {'form': form}
    return render_to_response('contacts/group.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**urls.py**

```
     (r'^group/new/$', 'contacts.views.group', {}, 'group_new'),
     (r'^group/edit/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'contacts.views.group', {}, 'group_edit'),
```

**model.py**

```
class Groups(models.Model):
    """
     Stores all groups.
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    active = models.BooleanField()
    modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True, auto_now=True, help_text="Shows when object was modified.")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, help_text="Shows when object was created.")

    #FK
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, related_name="user")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**error**

**IntegrityError at /contacts/group/edit/1/
(1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'user_id'")**

**UPDATE:
So this is what I have now, and it works, but only on edit not add. On add I still get the same error:**

```
def group(request, id=None):

    if id:
        # If we have an id try and get it and populate instance.
        group = get_object_or_404(Groups, pk=id)
        # If we have an instance check that it belongs to the login.
        if group.user != request.user:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
    else:
        # If we don't have an id get the instance (which is blank here) and populate it with the user.
        group = Groups(user=request.user)

    # If we had a POST then get the request post values.
    if request.method == 'POST':
    # Populate the form with the instance.
        form = GroupFrom(request.POST, instance=group)
        # Check we have valid data before saving trying to save.
        if form.is_valid():
            group.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Successfully Created/Updated Group')

    else:
        # Populate from at this point group with either be blank or have values.
        form = GroupFrom(instance=group)

    context = {'form': form}
    return render_to_response('contacts/group.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten up your code quite a bit:

```
class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Group

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(GroupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user = user

def group(request, id=None):
    if id:
        instance = get_object_or_404(Groups, pk=id)
    else:
        instance = None

    form = GroupFrom(request.POST or None, instance=instance, user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            group = form.save()
    return render_to_response('contacts/group.html', {'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

A simple override of the GroupForm's `__init__` allows you to hand in the user from the request, saving you from having to manually assign the value in the view. The `or` statement in the form's initialization allows you to do the instantiation in one place, rather than have a separate method if it's a GET request.

You have `unique=True` on your user foreign key property. Manually assigning it in the view won't catch any validation. Assigning the property when the form is instantiated should trigger a validation error before the form is submitted.

Comment: yes it was the unique=True, and I updated the my question to incorporate your idea (some what) and t works perfect. thank you Brandon.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
            group = Groups(
            name=form.cleaned_data['name'],
            description=form.cleaned_data['description'],
            active=form.cleaned_data['active'],
            user=request.user
        )
```

by :

```
        group.name=form.cleaned_data['name']
        group.description=form.cleaned_data['description']
        group.active=form.cleaned_data['active']
        group.user=request.user
```

Your `group = Groups(` is just erasing the previous value of the *group* variable.

Comment: I have updated to reflect (see question update), but I still get the error on new objects being saved.